# AJAX loop, calling function onload vs. manually in the console/code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 2 functions:

```
function find_existing_widgets(){
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open('GET', './_includes/check-load-user-settings.php', true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = open_existing_widgets;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}


function open_existing_widgets(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
    {
        xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
        root = xmlResponse.documentElement;

        var widget_id = root.getElementsByTagName('widget_id');
        var name = root.getElementsByTagName('name');
        var type = root.getElementsByTagName('type');
        var value = root.getElementsByTagName('value');

        for(i= 0; i< name.length; i++)
        {
            nameText = name.item(i).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            widgetID = widget_id.item(i).childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            //var value = name.item(i).firstChild.data;
            alert(nameText);
            nameText = nameText.replace(/\s+/g,'_');
            //alert(value); WORKS
            widget_creator();
            load = "./widgets/"+nameText+"/index.php?widget_id="+widgetID;
            //alert(load);  WORKS
            $('.wrapper:first .main_sec').load(load);
            $('.wrapper:first').fadeIn(1000);
        }

    }
}`
```

4 scenarios:

**one.** running the function `find_existing_widgets()` onload on the `<body>` tag and works perfect. runs once and shows data accordingly

**two.** running same function before the `</body>` tag like: `<script>find_existing_widgets()</scripts>` and this causes an infinite loop.

**three.** running the same function as `window.onload = find_existing_widgets();` in JS code. and this cause the same issue as two, infinite loop.

**four.** if I run it manually from the console it works perfectly.

Why the loop? what's the difference ?

Once there you'll see the execution that is looping. I am using AJAX, all the javascript can be seen in the dev tools in chrome.

**Example:**

josesebastianmanunta.com/animated3/login.php   user: smanunta pass: password

Comment: Is ```xmlHttp``` variable defined globally?

Comment: Why are you splitting up your functions like this?

Comment: i have tried both with xmlhttp global and local in the function

Comment: im splitting the functions for the `onreadystatechange` as far as i know this calls a function to handle the response. and i only handle on status 200 readystate 4

Comment: COULD BE because you are re-loading ```$('.wrapper:first .main_sec')``` every time, making load event propagate(event bubbling) to ```body``` tag in each loop of ```function open_existing_widgets( )```

Comment: a new instance of wrapper is created everytime its ran. its the widget creator function...ill check it out though ...this could be it.